# How many content type we can add to one list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type

How many content type we can add into the one list in SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard limit defined. But if you expect users to be able to use the library and content types I would recommend using as few as possible.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical limit but the suggested amount is around 10 - 15 content types per list/library.

This is a great article explaining the benefits: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/09/13/how-many-content-types-do-you-need-in-sharepoint-aspx/